# Maven to compile projects from source

Tags: maven, build

I am very new to maven. Our project is using maven and i am wanting to know if there is a way to force maven to build using source ONLY? Using no repo and not downloading anything. I have all the source required to build the whole project.

I just want to compile clean with out downloading or using the local repo.

Thanks

Comment: Maven will need some dependencies for itself, so unless you already downloaded them, I think there is no way it will work this way. I might be wrong, however...

Comment: Why would you like to build everything from source? Why not using already created packages (jar files) and only compile your own source?

Comment: Because the source is constantly changing, so we need to build from source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually not. The main reason is that you don't have all the sources.

Maven is a tool to manage dependencies for you. So you can say: "I need JUnit 4.11" and Maven will download it for you and make sure it's on the classpath when it's needed.

Now, if your project depends on JUnit 4.11, you can't compile it from source without the sources for JUnit. And Hamcrest. And probably a dozen other things.

So, no, you can't. Maven will compile the sources of your project but it won't try to locate the sources of all dependencies and compile them as well. Maven was built with the assumption that the binaries uploaded to Maven Central are correct and that the binaries were built from the attached source files (which are incomplete, btw, so you can't always build the project correctly from them).